# app crushing using a CursorAdapter Sunclass

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio, android-sqlite

The app crashes when i click on the item that should get me to this listview activity, I have NO idea what it is that I'm doing wrong or what I need to do to correct it. here is my CursorAdapter subclass to display a  listview:

```
package com.example.marhbabikapp;
```

```
import android.content.Context;import android.database.Cursor;import android.view.LayoutInflater;import android.view.View;import android.view.ViewGroup;import android.widget.CursorAdapter;import android.widget.ImageView;import android.widget.TextView;
```

```
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
```

```
public class DestinationCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {MyDBHandler myDBHandler;
```

```
public DestinationCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor,int flags ,MyDBHandler dbHandler) {
    super(context, cursor, flags);
    this.myDBHandler = dbHandler;;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_destinationtype, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView nameTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.destinationTextViewName);
    TextView descriptionTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.destinationTextViewDescription);
    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.destinationImageView);

    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDBHandler.DESTINATION_NAME));
    String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDBHandler.DESTINATION_DESCRIPTION));
    String imageUrl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDBHandler.PHOTO_URL));

    nameTextView.setText(name);
    descriptionTextView.setText(description);

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(imageUrl)
            //.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image) // Placeholder image while loading
            //.error(R.drawable.error_image) // Error image if Glide fails to load
            .into(imageView);
}
```

```
}
```

here is the types_screen activity when I tried to put my list view:

package com.example.marhbabikapp;

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;import android.content.Intent;import android.database.Cursor;import android.os.Bundle;import android.widget.ListView;import android.widget.TextView;import android.widget.Toast;
```

```
import java.util.Locale;
```

```
public class Types_screen extends AppCompatActivity {
```

```
private ListView mylistView;
private MyDBHandler dbHandler;
private DestinationCursorAdapter destinationCursorAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_types_screen);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String type = intent.getStringExtra("DESTINATION_TYPE");

    mylistView = findViewById(R.id.listViewDestinations);
    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this);

    Cursor cursor = null;

    if ("Historical".equals(type.trim())) {
        cursor = dbHandler.getHistoricalDestinationsCursor();
    } else if ("Natural".equals(type.trim())) {
        cursor = dbHandler.getNaturalDestinationsCursor();
    } else if ("Coastal".equals(type.trim())) {
        cursor = dbHandler.getCoastalDestinationsCursor();
    } else if ("Modern".equals(type.trim())) {
        cursor = dbHandler.getModernDestinationsCursor();
    } else if ("Cultural".equals(type.trim())) {
        cursor = dbHandler.getCulturalDestinationsCursor();
    } else if ("Saharian".equals(type.trim())) {
        cursor = dbHandler.getSaharianDestinationsCursor();
    } else if ("Snowy".equals(type.trim())) {
        cursor = dbHandler.getSnowyDestinationsCursor();
    }

        destinationCursorAdapter = new DestinationCursorAdapter(this, cursor, 0, dbHandler);
        mylistView.setAdapter(destinationCursorAdapter);

}
```

}

here is an instance of the methods:
public Cursor getSnowyDestinationsCursor() {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

```
    String[] projection = {
            DESTINATION_NAME,
            DESTINATION_DESCRIPTION,
            PHOTO_URL,
            REGION
    };

    String selection = SNOWY + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { "1" };

    return db.query(
            TABLE_DESTINATIONS,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
}
```

1. I tried to create another cursor adapter sub class but didnt change anything

Comment: Code formatting required

Answer (score 1):

Without doubt, but not eliminating other issues, you are missing a **CRUCIAL** aspect of a [CursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter).

***> The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work.***

i.e. You will encounter the following:-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist. Available columns: [destination_name, destination_description, photo_url, region]
```

What is not clearly explained is that this column is expected to be an integer (long) value that uniquely identifies a single row. The normally hidden **rowid** (for normal tables) fitting those requirements.

- in fact it is assumed that either the **rowid** column, or an alias of the **rowid** column is utilised.

  - if the column definition is `the_column_name_often_id_or_underscore_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`  (with or without `AUTOINCREMENT` *(which is a waste if not actually needed)*)

    - note **EXACTLY** `INTEGER` (case indepenant) **NOT** anything else, for example `INT`.

A quick fix, assuming a normal table (e,g, not a WITHOUT ROWID or virtual table), could be to use:-

```
    String[] projection = {
            "rowid AS " + BaseColumns._ID, /*<<<<<<<<<< ADDED */
            DESTINATION_NAME,
            DESTINATION_DESCRIPTION,
            PHOTO_URL,
            REGION
    };
```

This will overcome the illegal argument exception raised (assuming that the code gets this far).

**Demo of Issue**

To demonstrate using your code (many assumptions being made) then:-

```
2024-01-31 12:18:35.343 2228-2228/a.a.so77904630cursdoradapter D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    
    
    --------- beginning of crash
2024-01-31 12:18:35.344 2228-2228/a.a.so77904630cursdoradapter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: a.a.so77904630cursdoradapter, PID: 2228
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{a.a.so77904630cursdoradapter/a.a.so77904630cursdoradapter.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist. Available columns: [destination_name, destination_description, photo_url, region]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist. Available columns: [destination_name, destination_description, photo_url, region]
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:340)
        at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:180)
        at android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:157)
        at a.a.so77904630cursdoradapter.DestinationCursorAdapter.<init>(DestinationCursorAdapter.java:14)
        at a.a.so77904630cursdoradapter.MainActivity.setOrRefreshListView(MainActivity.java:56)
        at a.a.so77904630cursdoradapter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
```

- i.e. line 14 of the Destination CursorAdapter is where the exception occurs , which is `super(context, cursor, flags);`
- this message is abundantly clear.

**Fixed**

By simply changing to use:-

```
    String[] projection = {
            "rowid AS " + BaseColumns._ID, /* ADDED */
            DESTINATION_NAME,
            DESTINATION_DESCRIPTION,
            PHOTO_URL,
            REGION
    };
```

Then:-

[image]

- obviously your display may well be different. The App used was a mock-up based upon the available code, so other code was assumed (such as the layouts). As can be seen the ListView is showing a single row (this was inserted as part of the `onCreate` method of the MyDatabaseHandler).

---

***The mock-up code used***

The following is the mock-up code used to demonstrate the fix, ***please consider the comments***:-

**DestinationCursorAdapter**

```
public class DestinationCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {MyDBHandler myDBHandler;
   public DestinationCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags /*, MyDBHandler dbHandler NOT NEEDED????*/) {
      super(context, cursor, flags);
      //this.myDBHandler = dbHandler;
   }

   @Override
   public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
      return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_destinationtype, parent, false);
   }

   @Override
   public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
      TextView nameTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.destinationTextViewName);
      TextView descriptionTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.destinationTextViewDescription);
      ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.destinationImageView);

      String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDBHandler.DESTINATION_NAME));
      String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDBHandler.DESTINATION_DESCRIPTION));
      String imageUrl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDBHandler.PHOTO_URL));

      nameTextView.setText(name);
      descriptionTextView.setText(description);

      /*<<<<<<<<<< Commented out rather than try to handle Glide >>>>>>>>>>
      Glide.with(context)
              .load(imageUrl)
              //.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image) // Placeholder image while loading
              //.error(R.drawable.error_image) // Error image if Glide fails to load
              .into(imageView);
              */
   }
}
```

**MyDBHandler**

```
class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "the_database.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DESTINATION_NAME = "destination_name";
    public static final String DESTINATION_DESCRIPTION = "destination_description";
    public static final String TABLE_DESTINATIONS = "destinations";
    public static final String PHOTO_URL = "photo_url";
    public static final String REGION = "region";
    public static final String SNOWY = "snowy";
    public static final String ID = BaseColumns._ID; /* BaeColumns._ID equates to the string _id */

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    private volatile static MyDBHandler instance;

    private MyDBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();  /* will force an open and thus create */
    }

    public static MyDBHandler getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance==null) {
            instance = new MyDBHandler(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_DESTINATIONS + "(" +
                ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY " + /*<<<<< this would be an alias of the rowid column */
                "," + DESTINATION_NAME + " TEXT " +
                "," + DESTINATION_DESCRIPTION +" TEXT " +
                "," + PHOTO_URL + " TEXT " +
                "," + REGION + " TEXT " +
                "," + SNOWY + " TEXT " +
                ");");
        /* Add a single row for testing */ 
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DESTINATION_NAME,"DEST001");
        cv.put(DESTINATION_DESCRIPTION,"DESC001");
        cv.put(PHOTO_URL,"URL001");
        cv.put(REGION,"region001");
        cv.put(SNOWY,"whatever001");
        db.insert(TABLE_DESTINATIONS,null,cv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public Cursor getSnowyDestinationsCursor() { SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String[] projection = {
                "rowid AS " + BaseColumns._ID, /*<<<<<<<<<< ADDED to fix issue >>>>>>>>>> */
                DESTINATION_NAME,
                DESTINATION_DESCRIPTION,
                PHOTO_URL,
                REGION
        };

        String selection = SNOWY + " = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { "1" };

        return db.query(
                TABLE_DESTINATIONS,
                projection,
                /* selection, */ null, /* nulled to simplify i.e don;t have a WHERE clause */
                /*selectionArgs,*/ null, /* nulled, same reason as above */
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
    }
}
```

- perhaps consider the singleton approach used.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView mylistView;
    private MyDBHandler dbHandler;
    private DestinationCursorAdapter destinationCursorAdapter;

    private Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String type = intent.getStringExtra("DESTINATION_TYPE");

        mylistView = findViewById(R.id.listViewDestinations);
        dbHandler = /*new MyDBHandler(this);*/ MyDBHandler.getInstance(this);
        setOrRefreshListView();

        /*
        Cursor cursor = null; // should never need to force Cursor to be null

        if ("Historical".equals(type.trim())) {
            cursor = dbHandler.getHistoricalDestinationsCursor();
        } else if ("Natural".equals(type.trim())) {
            cursor = dbHandler.getNaturalDestinationsCursor();
        } else if ("Coastal".equals(type.trim())) {
            cursor = dbHandler.getCoastalDestinationsCursor();
        } else if ("Modern".equals(type.trim())) {
            cursor = dbHandler.getModernDestinationsCursor();
        } else if ("Cultural".equals(type.trim())) {
            cursor = dbHandler.getCulturalDestinationsCursor();
        } else if ("Saharian".equals(type.trim())) {
            cursor = dbHandler.getSaharianDestinationsCursor();
        } else if ("Snowy".equals(type.trim())) {
            cursor = dbHandler.getSnowyDestinationsCursor();
        }

        destinationCursorAdapter = new DestinationCursorAdapter(this, cursor, 0, dbHandler);
        mylistView.setAdapter(destinationCursorAdapter);
        */
    }
    /* Does as it's name says and thus would handle being called if the data has been changed or a different query selected/initiated*/
    private void setOrRefreshListView() {
        cursor = dbHandler.getSnowyDestinationsCursor();
        if (destinationCursorAdapter==null) {
            destinationCursorAdapter = new DestinationCursorAdapter(this,cursor, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER/*,dbHandler NOT NEEDED???*/);
            mylistView.setAdapter(destinationCursorAdapter);
        } else {
            destinationCursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
        }
    }
}
```

- Note selection of different queries ignored/excluded for demo
- Note the `setOrRefreshListView` method

**activity_main.xml** (layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        >
    </TextView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewDestinations"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

- nothing special other than background set so east to distinguish ListView

**item_destinationtype.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/destinationTextViewName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/destinationTextViewDescription"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </TextView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/destinationImageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

- again nothing special just an easily put together layout

---

**Additional - Why is the ID so useful/important **

As above if the _id column is used as per the expectations i.e. it is   the rowid or an alias of the rowid then it uniquely identifies the row in question.

For example it can be passed to data operations. In fact the ListView's Listeners pass this value to the respective `on....` method if set which can then drive actions.

Extended the above answer to demonstrate. Consider the following method in the MyDBHandler:-

```
public void updateRowThenAddNewRow(long _id) {
    db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_DESTINATIONS + " SET " + DESTINATION_DESCRIPTION + "=" + DESTINATION_DESCRIPTION + "||'_click_' WHERE rowid=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(_id)});
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DESTINATION_NAME,"DEST_" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    cv.put(DESTINATION_DESCRIPTION, DESTINATION_DESCRIPTION+System.currentTimeMillis());
    cv.put(PHOTO_URL,"photo_url");
    cv.put(REGION,"region");
    db.insert(TABLE_DESTINATIONS,null,cv);
}
```

- obviously not of any practical use but this allows a row to be updated and also for a new row to be added.

In conjunction with the above also consider the following change in the activity (i.e. the `setOrRefreshListView` method):-

```
private void setOrRefreshListView() {
    cursor = dbHandler.getSnowyDestinationsCursor();
    if (destinationCursorAdapter==null) {
        destinationCursorAdapter = new DestinationCursorAdapter(this,cursor, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER/*,dbHandler NOT NEEDED???*/);
        mylistView.setAdapter(destinationCursorAdapter);
        /* START of Extra code */
        mylistView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                /* i and l will both be the _id value */
                dbHandler.updateRowThenAddNewRow(l);
                setOrRefreshListView();
                return true;
            }
        });
        /* End of Extra code */
    } else {
        destinationCursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }
}
```

- note the use of **`l`** being passed to the `updateRowThenAddNewRow` method (the _id value)
- also note that the overidden **`on`** method calls the setOrRefreshListview method to refresh the ListView after the update and add.

Now if the App is run  then:-

[image]

If the item in the ListView is long clicked then:-

[image]

- i.e. the original row's description now has *click* appended and a new row has appeared

If the new row is long clicked:-

[image]

If the original row is long clicked again then:-

[image]

and so on (of course the practicality of the demo is useless and even dangerous but it does demonstrate how useful just the single **`_id`** value can be).